# Getting errors when Importing files to SQL Server 2012

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012

I have power-shell code below, trying to import an excel file into DB1.

```
   $dir = "\\server\folder\"
        $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*Notes*"} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
        Write-Output "The latest file is: $latest"
        Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "instance1" -DatabaseName "DB1" -SchemaName dbo -TableName Table1 -InputData $latest -Force
```

Am getting into errors when I run this code, see below:

```
Write-SqlTableData : A mapping between .Net type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' and SQL type for column 'Directory' was not found. Consider removing the column with that type and repeat the operation
```

I have googled this error and don't seem to get any help. Anyone who can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear; you need to

- narrow `Get-ChildItem` output to files (i.e. `.xsl` or `.xslx`, in all likelihood), and
- supply `-InputData` as `$latest.Name` **string** instead of `$latest` **object** of  `System.IO.FileSystemInfo` type (supposedly: it's *only my guess*, not having SQL-related cmdlets installed).

```
$dir = "\\server\folder\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | 
  Where-Object {$_.name -like "*Notes*.xsl*"} | 
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
Write-Output "The latest file is: $latest"
Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "instance1" -DatabaseName "DB1" -SchemaName dbo -TableName Table1 -InputData $latest.Name -Force
```

or, instead of `Where-Object`, use [-Filter parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem) for `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet as

```
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*Notes*.xsl*" | 
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

> **-Filter**
>
> Specifies a filter in the provider's format or language. The value of
>   this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. The syntax of the filter,
>   including the use of wildcards, depends on the provider. Filters are
>   more efficient than other parameters, because the provider applies
>   them when retrieving the objects, rather than having Windows
>   PowerShell filter the objects after they are retrieved from the
>   provider.

Please note that `-InputData` parameter *might be* single-quoted `$latest.FullName`:

`Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "instance1" … -InputData` **`"'$($latest.FullName)'"`** `-Force`